# APEX: How to link application log-in credentials to a table in back-end database

Tags: oracle11g, frontend, oracle-apex

I have made a database and now I am trying to make a front-end application using oracle apex 4(default with oracle-xe 11g). I have included the following table for user credentials in my database.

```
Manager(managerid{PK},name,username,password)
```

I know I can create many end-user accounts from the apex for an application. But, users of application will be managers only and I have a table for them in database so it would be illogical to create separate accounts and information when I have them already in database.

My question is, how can I link the authorization of front-end application with the above table?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom authentication scheme and authorize

how to refer following http://allthingsoracle.com/custom-authentication-in-apex/

and http://oraclecafe.com/2013/04/11/apex-custom-authentication-scheme/